# Drag and drop takes me to a different website if false or restarts animation if true

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, css-animations

I've got this animation: http://codepen.io/tiamat/pen/Jrdvx
When the colored circle goes into the black one it restarts animation. When it does not go into it it takes me to circle.com website. Can I stop both of these actions? I would like if successful, not to restart the animation, but the colored circle to remain in the black one.

html:

```
<div id="intreg" style="border:1px solid #000000; width:750px; height: 550px;" >
 <div id="jos">
  <div id="square_drop"ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
     <div id="circle_drop"ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
</div>
  <div id="sus">
<div id="triangle_drop"ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>

 <div id="square" draggable="true"ondragstart="return dragStart(event)"></div>
     <div id="circle" draggable="true"ondragstart="return dragStart(event)"></div>
<div id="triangle" draggable="true"ondragstart="return dragStart(event)"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

javascript:

```
function dragStart(ev) {
   ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
   ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,100,100);
   return true;
}
function dragEnter(ev) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return true;
}
function dragOver(ev) {
     event.preventDefault();
}
function dragDrop(ev) {
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
   ev.stopPropagation();
   return false;
}
```

css:

```
#square { 
-webkit-animation: move4 3s forwards linear ;
    -moz-animation: move4 3s forwards  linear ;
    -o-animation: move4 3s forwards linear ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move4 {
    0% {margin-bottom: -400px;margin-left:-100px;}
    100% {margin-top: -130px;margin-left: 400px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move4 {
0% {margin-top: 1400px;margin-left:-100px;}
    100% {margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 400px;}
}
@-o-keyframes move4 {
0% {margin-bottom: -400px;margin-left:-100px;}
    100% {margin-top: -130px;margin-left: 400px;}
}
#circle {
-webkit-animation: move5 3s forwards linear ;
    -moz-animation: move5 3s forwards  linear ;
    -o-animation: move5 3s forwards linear ;}
@-webkit-keyframes move5 {
    0% {margin-top: 1000px;margin-left:-100px;}
    100% {margin-top: -40px;margin-left: 150px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move5 {
0% {margin-top: 1000px;margin-left:-100px;}
    100% {margin-top: -40px;margin-left: 150px;}
}
@-o-keyframes move5 {
0% {margin-top: 1000px;margin-left:-100px;}
    100% {margin-top: -40px;margin-left: 150px;}
}
#triangle { 
  -webkit-animation: move6 3s forwards linear ;
    -moz-animation: move6 3s forwards  linear ;
    -o-animation: move6 3s forwards linear ;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move6 {
0% {margin-top: 1000px;margin-left:-100px;}
    100% {margin-top: -120px;margin-left: 20px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move6 {
0% {margin-top: 1000px;margin-left:-100px;}
    100% {margin-top: -120px;margin-left: 20px;}
}
@-o-keyframes move6 {
0% {margin-top: 1000px;margin-left:-100px;}
    100% {margin-top: -120px;margin-left: 20px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where the colored circle is dropped on the black one:  When you append the dropped element, it is re-rendered in its new location, including the animation you specified in the style.  You could try creating a class that removes the animations

```
#circle.stay {
  -webkit-animation: none !important;
  -moz-animation: none !important;
  -o-animation: none !important;
}
```

and add this class to the element before appending it to its new home:

```
function dragDrop(ev) {
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   var el = document.getElementById(data);
   el.className="stay";
   ev.target.appendChild(el);
   ev.stopPropagation();
   return false;
}
```

For the case where it misses, add an ondrop handler to the `body` element that cancels the drag

```
<body ondrop="return false">
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kagsk)